# Python login script to CSRF protected web site

Tags: python, csrf

I am trying to create simple login script to rol.redhat.com web site.
Here is my example:

```
import sys
import requests

URL = 'https://rol.redhat.com/rol/rhz/login'

# CSRF token
client = requests.session()
client.get(URL)
token = client.cookies['csrftoken']

# LOGIN
login_data = dict(username='USERNAME', password='PASSWORD',csrftoken=token)
r = client.post(URL, data=login_data, headers=dict(Referer=URL))
print r.status_code
print r.text
```

But I am receiving this:

> 403

(...)

> ## Forbidden (403)
>
> CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

(...)

What is wrong in my script?

Comment: You are probably missing a referrer or cookie or something that the site gives your browser to pass to the site on subsequent requests. Try using e.g. Fiddler to snoop on headers/info passing between your browser and the website as you browse to the pages you are interested in - you will have to reproduce something specific about that in your python.

Comment: Look at the page in a debugger and you'll see there's a hidden input field called 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' which you're not sending. My guess would be you need to send the cookie 'csrftoken' AND the form input value csrfmiddlewaretoken. As @barny suggests, there may also be a header.